# Is there a (nearly) fail-safe check-list to ensure that your python scripts work across all Linux distributions?

Tags: python, linux, cross-platform, compatibility

I don't have quick access to many operating systems so I can't test each linux distro to ensure my scripts work. but I'd like to list what platforms the scripts I develop will work on. I develop mostly on Fedora and Cent-OS. I'm not sure what the key differences are between each of the Linux flavors and/or if there are things that will prevent my scripts from working properly across OS's **if I use things like ANSI escape sequences or any code that uses a system or subproccess call.**

**Edit** Is there a rule of thumb that I can use to know which flavors my scripts developed in Fedora will work on?

Comment: it depends on what the script do and how. this question is so abstract, it'll be hard for anyone to give you an answer.

Comment: In general, any built-in module like subprocess should perform across Linux platforms equally well, given of course that there are documented exceptions in each module like subprocess. There's no general rule, take it case by case!